# Qt: Immediately start thread, without delay of main event loop

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

The following member function runs in the main event loop.

```
    void MyClass::update()
    {
        Data x = m_interpolator->getRequest(m_interpolationRequest)
        // non blocking new calclulation request
        m_interpolator->asyncRequestCalculations(++m_interpolationRequest);
        // I want to run doCalculations from now on in a second thread
        ... updates ... // takes some time
    }
    <-- earliest time when doCalculations() will be triggered
```

With each call of `update` I request a new calculation, which I will fetch in the next cycle.

`CInterpolator (m_interpolator)` is a `QObject` in a different thread (using [moveToThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread)). `asyncRequestCalculations` invokes (non-blocking) a call of `CInterpolator::doCalculations` (same as sending a signal to the `doCalculations` slot).

It works, but is too slow. What happens is that the signal for `doCalculations` is properly scheduled, but `CInterpolator` only called **after** function `update` has been left. Understandable, this is how the Qt event loop works.

But for me it wastes the time of the `... updates ...` block. I want the calculation taking place in parallel to `... updates ...`. **How could I accomplish this?**

Comment: You mean the result is ready when `... updates ...` is still busy?

Comment: No! But the calculation can already start in parallel, it does not need to finish. Updated above to make it more obvious

Comment: if doCalculations isn't triggered then my guess is that it *isn't* in a different thread. Did you properly call moveToThread on it?

Comment: Yes, it is correctly having the affinity of a different thread, in the real code I check by an QASSERT. My issue is how I best trigger the 2nd thread. I am aware of signal / slots as one means, but the signal will only be handled by the main event loop after updates has finished.

Comment: Show more code! if you `m_interpolator` is moved properly to other thread (no parent) than you should no call its methods directly from main thread. You should use slot-signal mechanism which will do inter thread communication. Use signal to schedule work for `m_interpolator` and use signals to report progress of this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main event loops are supposed to be fast operations, which should be executed continuously. Therefore, that is why you observe that the application is too slow: the refresh rate is slower than it should be.

It is not recommended to use **slow** operations in update/event loop.

By the way, in order to have parallel execution, you would have to use [threads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/).
One code *snippet* should be:

```
void MyClass::update()
    {
        Data x = m_interpolator->getRequest(m_interpolationRequest)
        // non blocking new calclulation request
        m_interpolator->asyncRequestCalculations(++m_interpolationRequest);
        // I want to run doCalculations from now on in a second thread

       std::thread first(update());
    }
```

Comment: As I have written, CInterpolator is a QObject residing in another thread http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread , so its affinity is that of the new thread. And it is not that the application is not responsive, especially not because as I have taken the calculation out of the main event loop. Only the delay until the calculation starts is undesirable.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a code snippet of thread usage. Better encapsulate the updates in a function that would be executed by thread named **first**

Comment: As of the edit: So your recommendation is to use std::thread instead of Qt's thread mechanism. Is that the idea?

Comment: Qt thread mechanism can be used too without any problem. I have provided the std one trying to provide a more _universal_ version.